# TCP (Net) Node.JS. Отправить сообщение всем пользователям

Tags: node.js, tcp

Если приходит сообщение от пользователя, то оно обратно отправляется ему же, но не всем. Как сделать чтобы отправлялось всем? Межпроцессное взаимодействие?

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer((c) => {

  c.on('data', function (data) {
    c.write(data.toString());
  });

});

server.listen(5050, () => {
  console.log('Ok');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
const net = require('net');

let openSockets = [];
const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    openSockets.push(socket);

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        openSockets.forEach((s) => {
            s.write(data.toString());
        })
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        openSockets = openSockets.filter((s) => {
            return s !== socket;
        });
    });
});

server.listen(5050, () => {
    console.log('Ok');
});
```